# What does a "well-received question" and a "positive question record" mean?

Tags: support

I see that I was just awarded the "Inquisitive" badge. Looking at the explanation of this badge, it says:

> Asked a well-received question on 30 separate days, and maintained a
>   positive question record

I'm guessing that this requires at least 30 questions because the questions must be asked on 30 different days but I am unclear what makes a question "well-received" and what a positive question record means.

I'm guessing a positive question record means that I have less than x% of my questions with negative net votes but that is also unclear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A set of new "asking questions" badges were rolled out yesterday. These are described more fully on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges).

In a nutshell, "well-received" means

> open, not deleted, and has a score > 0

And "positive question record" means

> (total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted)/total questions >= 0.5

Comment: That helps a lot. Thanks! Why don't we add this to the tag description (I do not see a way to edit it)?

Comment: @earthling badge descriptions are global to all SE sites, suggestions for changing them should go to MSE